# Group with simple relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on the following algebra problem:

Prove that if elements $a$ and $b$ of some group satisfy the relations

1) $a^5 = b^3 = 1$ and

2) $b^{-1}ab = a^2$

then $a = 1$.

Here is an example of what I've tried:

If $a^5 = 1$, then using relation 2) , multiplying on the right by $a^3$ on both sides gives *$b^{-1}aba^3 = 1$.

If $b^3 = 1$, then using relation 2), multiplying on the left by $b^4$ on both sides gives **$ab = b^4a^2$.

Then, I tried substituting ** into *. Unfortunately, this just gets me relation 1) back again. It seems that my methods to exploit the relations always end up in simply recovering relation 1), rather than showing $a = 1$.

Is there anything more clever I can try here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $b^{-1}ab=a^2$, $b^3 =1$ and $a^5=1$, then
$$\begin{align*}
b^{-2}ab^2 &= b^{-1}(b^{-1}ab)b\\
&= b^{-1}a^2b\\
&= (b^{-1}ab)^2\\
&= (a^2)^2 = a^4 = a^{-1}.
\end{align*}$$
So therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
a&= b^{-3}ab^3\\
&= b^{-1}(b^{-2}ab^2)b\\
&= b^{-1}(a^{-1})b\\
&= (b^{-1}ab)^{-1}\\
&= (a^2)^{-1}\\
&= a^3.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, $a=a^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Your original method fails because if we analyse what you have done:

We begin with $$b^{-1}ab=a^2$$

Pre-multiply by $b (=b^4)$ (**) $$ab=ba^2$$

Post-multiply by $a^3$ $$aba^3=b$$

Pre-multiply by $b^{-1}$ (*) $$b^{-1}aba^3=1$$

Post-multiply by $a^2$ $$b^{-1}ab=a^2$$

which is to be expected!

$aba^3=b$ is probably the best point to break, yielding $a^{-1}ba=a^{-2}ba^{-2}$, but Arturo's answer has already been accepted.